# Zyxel NSA310 - PHP displays source instead of executing

Tags: php, mysql, nas

I've got a problem with installing PHP on my Zyxel NSA 310.

I installed the PHP plugin and I can access my phpMyAdmin for editing MySQL database, but I don't know how to execute my PHP script. *Where* should I put my .php files to see the results of my code?

I've tried to put my index.php file in many locations, on my ZYXEL hard drive but the output is raw - the script doesn't execute, I see the source of PHP file. When I test this script on the Apache server on my computer, everything is ok. In addition, it can't be a problem with `chmod`, because I allowed reading, writing and executing files in all the directories.

Comment: Zyxel NSA310 is a NAS ( network attached storage ) not a web server. You cannot do what you like.

Comment: usually the webserver root is /var/www for apache.
if you can serve files from directory, the source code output from php files in this directory means, you haven't installed or enabled php interpretator. Usually you need to install mod_php apache plugin for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to install/enable PHP-MySQL-PhpMyAdmin (System Settings > Package - what you probably did).

Then you have to create a share - say "www" (Sharing > Shares) and publish it (Applications > Web Publishing - select "www" > Publish selected share).

Afterwards you can put your php script into "www" folder and test it in browser:
after entering NSA310/www the address changes to NSA310/MyWeb/www and you should see a list of files - your script should be there; click on it and it should execute.

Answer (score 0):

I have a nsa540 zyxel, i make all you describe, install phpmyadmin, create www share and publish in web, i can go with my browser in the share, i see the list of files, but the php script won't execute... I see the code script but he won't execute, for exemple i will install dokuwiki, and when i go to the page where is the install.php file, i'can't continue, i only see the code of the file...

I have make many procedure for ffp-stick to have possibilities to install lightppd, but impossible to have thirdsparty repositorie, the procedure don't work = nothing... I create the web_prefix, but nothing...

When i install the wordpress inside the repositorie official, it's ok.

Comment: You need to clarify your answer with technical details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i write in english but i'm swiss french... sorry in technical english this is a little bit difficult. I have exactly the same probleme as descibe in the fisrt question by Jackub ! What other information to you want for me helping ? Very thanks you in advance

Comment: I understand. Often, other contributors will help edit questions for clarity, as long as you have enough information for them to get an idea of what you are expressing. With that said, another answer for this question was already accepted, so don't worry about it for now.

Comment: Thanks you for your time, I repost my question like Jackub : I've got a problem with installing PHP on my Zyxel NSA 540. I installed PHP plugin and I can access my phpMyAdmin for editing mysql database, but I don't know how to execute my PHP script. Where should I put my .php files to see the results of my code? I've tried to put my index.php file in many locations, on my ZYXEL hard drive but the output is raw - the script doesn't execute, I see the source of php file. How can y executing files in php in my share www ?

Comment: What adress have typed in your broswer? In my case works only  http://[NAS IP ADRESS]/MyWeb/[SHARE NAME]/

Comment: I Jakub, thansk for rour reply. I use the same way http://[NAS IP or DNS no-ip.org from Ext]/MyWeb/www] with html index to redirect or http://[NAS IP or DNS no-ip.org from Ext]/MyWeb/www/dokuwiki] or http://[NAS IP or DNS no-ip.org from Ext]/MyWeb/www/dokuwiki/install.php]. In all case, I only see the script contained in the php file from dokuwiki, but he won't execute. I have the latest firmware V5.03(AATB.0) and all other function in the NAS are allright... Thanks you in advance